# Gmail api messages/list Q after:{timestamp} doe not work properly

Tags: gmail-api

Good time!

I'm trying to get the list of message and to filter them I use `Q after:{timestamp}`

I do the following query

[image]

After getting the message id I do a query to get the details of the message:
[image]

As you can see `timestamp` in the query and `internalDate` of the message are the same.

When I increment timestamp value to `1559717792` and do a query I get the same result:

[image]

In my view, the result should be empty because the `internalDate` less than `1559717792`. Is it an issue or is it my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: I have observed that you cut some values in the time stamp, which I think is an important part of it. Try the query using the proper length of timestamp, instead of `1559717792` should it be proper to use `1559717792000`.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 as for time ranges, gmail api works with seconds, not milliseconds

Comment: BTW does after:1559717793 produce expected results?  (I wonder if it's a rounding issue with the milliseconds value under the covers.)

Comment: @EricD it does!

Comment: @EricD i did several tests. Sometimes, like the discussed issue, (x + 1) doesn't work but (x+2) works fine. In some cases, i should increment the timestamp on 3 seconds to get an expected result.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked.  I've updated my answer to mention this issue around rounding that I discovered.

Comment: Roger.  I imagine that second-level precision wasn't intended and that may be one reason it's not documented/supported.  Can still err on the safe side (few seconds before what you really need) and post-filter client side.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail API uses the same search syntax as web interface and it's documented here:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

Specifically it never says "after:<epochSeconds>" works but it only gives an option for a formatted date "after:YYYY/MM/DD".  Emperically the <epochSeconds> does seem to work, but it's not documented (so beware that it's not guaranteed to be supported and may break at any time) and also it seems that there may be some rounding issues within the same second (so you may have to add or remove a second to always get the results you want if you need that level of accuracy).

Comment: There is a page on developers.google.com. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering